# queryString containing multiline Arabic text

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to call an asp.net page from javascript with queryString having Arabic text. It shows me an error when goes online but works smoothly on the local server. When arabic value is small then it works smoothly problem arises when arabic text is in multiple lines.

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "Empty/emptyGovt2.aspx",
        data: "arKeyword="+encodeURIComponent($("#txt_arKeywords").val(),
        success: function(data) {    
             diaL("Details Updated Successfully");                  

         },
          error: function(){
              diaL('Error Occurred');
          }
 });
```

Comment: You forgot to say *what* error you see. Include the exact error message.

Comment: error: function(){
              diaL('Error Occurred');
          }

Comment: how do i retrive jason value in asp.net page
i was using request.querystring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont use `get` with long and complex datas use `post`

```
$.ajax({
        url: "Empty/emptyGovt2.aspx",
        type:"POST",
        data: {
            "arKeyword" :$("#txt_arKeywords").val(),
            "OrgId" : newParentOfficeID 
             // etc
           },
        success: function(data) {    
             diaL("Details Updated Successfully");                  

         },
          error: function(){
              diaL('Error Occurred');
          }
 });
```

And on the php you can access the values as `$_POST['OrgId']` etc

Comment: it displays an error


$.ajax({
                url: "Empty/emptyGovt2.aspx",
                type: "POST",
                data: {"OrgId=" + newParentOfficeID + " &&districtID=" + districtIDg + " &&streetID=" + streetIDg + " &&POBox=" + $("#txtPOBoxNew").val() + " &&Zip=" + $("#txtZipNew").val() + " &&txtHotLine=" + $("#txtHotLineNew").val() + " &&Telephone=" + txtP + " &&Email=" + arrEmail + " &&Web=" + arrWeb + " &&Fax=" + arrFax + " &&juricionVal=" + juricditionVal +" &&tollFree="+ $("#tollFreeNew").val()+" &&uniFied="+$("#uniFiedNew").val()+" &&enKeyword="+$("#txt_enKeywords").val()},

Comment: look on my format `data: {"arKeyword" :$("#txt_arKeywords").val() }`

Comment: i wrote like this
is this write

 data: {"OrgId=" + newParentOfficeID + " &&uniFied= "+ $("#uniFiedNew").val()+" &&enKeyword="+$("#txt_enKeywords").val()},

Comment: No you cant write like that for `post` use my format..i already updated my answer

Comment: displays an error in jqury library


catch (l) { } e.async && e.timeout > 0 && setTimeout(function() { x && !E && g("timeout") }, e.timeout); try { x.send(n === "POST" || n === "PUT" || n === "DELETE" ? e.data : null) } catch (m) { c.handleError(e, x, null, m); d() } e.async || g(); return x

Comment: $.ajax({
                url: "Empty/emptyGovt2.aspx",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    "OrgId":newParentOfficeID, 
                    "districtID":districtIDg,
                    "streetID":streetIDg,
                    "POBox":$("#txtPOBoxNew").val(),
                    "Zip":$("#txtZipNew").val(),
                    "txtHotLine":$("#txtHotLineNew").val(),
                    "arKeyword":$("#txt_arKeywords").val(),
                    "enKeyword":$("#txt_enKeywords").val()
                 },
                  dataType: 'json',

Comment: still you are not using the format as iam using....look carefully on my answer and use it..

Comment: wat i to to do 
put space b/w : like this

"Email" : arrEmail,

Comment: how do i retrive jason value in asp.net page
i was using request.querystring

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use `POST` and `dataType:'json'` or `'text'`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Empty/emptyGovt2.aspx",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {"arKeyword" : $("#txt_arKeywords").val()}, //<----json objects
    dataType: 'json',                                 //<----dataType
    success: function(data) {  
      // retriev json response 
       var respData = $.parseJSON(data);
       $.each(respData, function(i, item){
          console.log(item);
       });

         diaL("Details Updated Successfully");                  

     },
      error: function(){
          diaL('Error Occurred');
      }
 });
```

and make sure to return json from `'Empty/emptyGovt2.aspx'`

Comment: how do i retrive jason value in asp.net page
i was using request.querystring

Comment: use `$.each()` and parse the json `$.parseJSON(data);`. see the updated answer.

Comment: need to retrive values of urls at page load

wen i use get then i use querystring to those values now wat i hve to to retrive values of post methos